# Why didn't Mike Hanlon's diary disappear?

Tags: it

In *IT* (Stephen King) there are parts of a diary written by Mike Hanlon, one of the main characters of the novel that fight Pennywise.

This diary was found in the library's safe, and it was found after the epilogue of the story.

In the novel, the Losers (the group of kids that fights IT) defeat IT twice, the first time they only hurt IT (summer of 1958), the second they kill IT definitely (summer of 1985).

After the first fight, the Losers starts to forget everything about that summer, even the relationships that were holding the group.

Then, when they return to fight IT in the 1985, they start to remember everything, but after IT's death, they start to forget once again, this time (it seems) permanently.

Not only the Losers forget everything, but everyone that is linked to the story, starts to forget.

A proof of that forgetting process, is explained in the last part of the Mike's diary: he says that the numbers of the Losers that he wrote in his rubric are fading out.

So, why the diary did not fade out? Shouldn't it fade like the rubric?

Comment: As a first thought, this is coming from the guy whose memories are fading.  He could be doing it himself, or his mind could be doing it for him.  It's not like there's a giant eldritch thingy hanging around anymore to coordinate the memory wipe.

Comment: I always thought it was the turtle (http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Maturin) trying to help them have something to prepare them when phase 2 came around.

Comment: @KevinMilner the Turtle died between the two phases, it cannot be the reason of it

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: **no**. Remember that the diary was primarily a compilation of Derry's history surrounding It (Mike titled the diary "Derry: An Unauthorised Town History") in which he collated the recounts of people and other manuscripts. All of that would remain.

But, any recollection of the Loser's (by the town's folk, and in writing) would likely fade away from memory forever. Remember, they made a covenant (the Ritual of Chud) to return to Derry should It ever resurface. After the Loser's (sans Mike) moved away from Derry as adults, it was this pact which still bound all 7 of them both together and to Derry.

But, at the end of the book - when It is vanquished - the deed is done. **Derry is free from It, and so the Losers are free to move on with their lives as well. If anything, the fading of their names from Mike's diary is symbolic of this.** Derry was like a very bad dream which they can finally wake up from.

Here are some quote which allude to this:

> "...the address and number have faded still more, but they are still
>   legible. No go, Joe. Got a recorded phone-company voice telling me
>   service to that number has been cancelled. **Was Ben fat, or did he have
>   something like a club foot?** [even Mike has begun to forget]"
>
> ...
>
> "I’m almost done with this diary now—and I suppose a diary is all that
>   it will ever be, and that the story of Derry’s old scandals and
>   eccentricities has no place outside these pages. That’s fine with me;
>   I think that, when they let me out of here tomorrow, **it might finally
>   be time to start thinking about some sort of new life**." *It, Derry: The
>   Last Interlud*e. (emphasis mine)